# It is possible to deduplicate contacts entered in a Webform?

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm, duplicate-contacts

I haven't found this issue in any other topic, sorry if it's been already asked.

I'm trying to automatically deduplicate contacts which enter to Civi from a registration Webform, but I haven't found a way. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: On top of @Catorghans answer I highly recommend to check out this post: https://civicrm.org/blogs/spidersilk/understanding-civicrm-dedupe-rules

Answer (score 3):

They are merged, based on the "Unsupervised" deduplication rules: civicrm/contact/deduperules?reset=1

By default the unsupervised rules for individuals are based on email-only.
So if someone fills in a Webform with an email that already exists in civicrm then those data will be merged.

You can change these rules: http://book.civicrm.org/user/common-workflows/deduping-and-merging/

Comment: You can also choose a custom dedupe rule in the webform directly